# Custom notification sound no longer working

Tags: ios, cordova, audio, apple-push-notifications

I have a Windows service which will send notifications to our iOS app using Apple's push notification service.  We were using a custom notification sound which was playing when the notification appeared on the device.  Last week after the iOS 10.3.3 update was released, we've found that the custom sound is no longer being played.  This is the message we're sending to APS:

```
{
    {
        "aps": {
            {
                "alert": "Alert message",
                "badge": 5,
                "sound": "mysound.mp3"
            }
        },
        "acme1": "bar",
        "acme2": 42
    }
}
```

Our app has not changed, and the custom sound is no longer playing even on devices which have not yet updated to iOS 10.3.3, including devices that can't update past iOS 9.

I'm not exactly sure were to start looking to diagnose the issue; the mobile app is built using Cordova.

Comment: Does the sound file persist on the device?

Comment: @Shubham Not quite sure what you mean, but I believe the audio file is included in the app when its installed.  At any rate, it was working just over a week ago, and we have not published a new version, which makes me suspect something possibly changed on Apple's side of things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised it ever worked at all with the mp3 file type.

According to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW10):

> You can package the audio data in an **aiff**, **wav**, or **caf** file. Because they are played by the system-sound facility, custom sounds must be in one of the following audio data formats:
>
> - Linear
> - PCM
> - MA4 (IMA/ADPCM)
> - µLaw
> - aLaw

Try converting it to one of the supported formats and packages and it should start working again.  See the docs for details on how to do that.

Comment: I agree with @Chris Allwein you should try with wav, aiff or caf files but first make sure that there should be a file in the application with provided name.

Comment: Apparently its been like this for years.  I'll give this a try though as I believe we have the same sound in three other formats, all bundled into the app.  One is WAV, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

## iOS Notifcation custom sound is worked (When app in Foreground,Background,and Terminated)

> Local and remote notifications can specify custom alert sounds to be played when the notification is delivered. You can package the audio data in an aiff, wav, or caf file. Because they are played by the system-sound facility, custom sounds must be in one of the following audio data formats:

- Linear PCM
- MA4 (IMA/ADPCM)
- µLaw
- aLaw

**Note:-**
Custom sounds must be **under 30 seconds** when played. If a custom sound is over that limit, the **default system sound is played instead**.

- Add files to the Xcode project root.
  [Add file to Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3GRa.png)
- Make sure Add to targets is selected when adding files so that they are automatically add to the bundle resources
  [add the file to copy bundle resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkZ1N.png)

**After that you need to set custom Sound name in app Payload:-**

```
     payload
    {
    aps =     {
        alert = "Hello World";
        badge = 1;
        sound = "iosTune.aiff"; // default;
              };
    }
```

**Final:-** when notification will receive in any stage of application then custom sound will play instead of Default sound.

Comment: You seem to have plagiarised a large part of your answer from https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html or somewhere similar. Please give attribution where appropriate or your posts will be flagged for plagiarism.